# Match after Prefix, when the Ending Delimiter Varies

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

**These are some of my test Cases:**

```
{APIDETAILS=FOO, BAR, SING, RUN, OP1/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP1/OPSUB2/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP2/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING}
{APIDETAILS=FOO, OP1/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP1/OPSUB2/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP2/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING}
{APIDETAILS=FOO, O.P.OP3/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP1/OPSUB2/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP2/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING}
{APIDETAILS=FOO, OP.PO.OP4/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP1/OPSUB2/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP2/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING}
{OP1/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP1/OPSUB2/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP2/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, APIDETAILS=FOO}
{OP1/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP1/OPSUB2/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP2/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, APIDETAILS=FOO, SING, BAR}
{OP1/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP1/OPSUB2/RESULT=SOMETHING, OP2/OPSUB1/RESULT=SOMETHING, APIDETAILS=FOO, BAR, SING
```

**Note:** '}' is intentionally missing in the last line.

**What I want to match:**
Everything followed by APIDETAILS, but only until end of APIDETAILS. The end if clearly not defined (look for above test cases for different scenarios)

**The Regex I came up with:**

```
(?:APIDETAILS=)(.*?)(?:}|\/|$)
```

**What I'm able to match:**

1. FOO, BAR, SING, RUN, OP1
2. FOO, OP1
3. FOO, O.P.OP3
4. FOO, OP.PO.OP4
5. FOO
6. FOO, SING, BAR
7. FOO, BAR, SING

**Question:** How do I get rid of some noise in matches 1,2,3,4 above and end up having only with the following?

**What I need to match:**

1. FOO, BAR, SING, RUN
2. FOO
3. FOO
4. FOO
5. FOO
6. FOO, SING, BAR
7. FOO, BAR, SING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
(?m)(?<=APIDETAILS=).*?(?=,\s*\S+=|}|$)
```

See the matches in **[the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/3)**.

- `(?m)` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- The lookbehind `(?<=APIDETAILS=)` asserts that what precedes is `APIDETAILS=`
- `.*?` lazily matches chars up to...
- A place where the lookahead `(?=,\s*\S+=|}|$)` can assert that what follows is a comma followed by optional whitespace, non-space chars and `=`, OR `|` the `}` character OR the end of the line `$`

Answer (score 2):

Use a **Positive Lookahead**:

```
APIDETAILS=(.*?)(?=}|,\s*\S+=|$)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ6lC8/4)

Or simply add to your non-capturing group:

```
APIDETAILS=(.*?)(?:}|,\s*\S+=|$)
```